# Doing an ASM call / ret in C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I try to do a simple call / ret sequence in assembly (from c code compiled with GCC), by manually writing the ret op code, and making a call to the ret address:

```
void *addr;
addr = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
// Writing the ret op code
((char*)addr)[0] = 0xC3;
// Going to addr with the ret
asm volatile("call *%0" : : "r" (addr));
```

But I get a segmentation fault. Anyone would know why, and how to correct ?

Comment: Is the page executable? Do you not have to mark it as `PROT_EXEC`?

Comment: Also why use inline asm to make the call? A C function call should work perfectly fine.

Comment: Typecast to a function pointer and call: `(*(void)(*)addr)();`

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Your cast is wrong. It should be `((void (*)())addr)();`

Comment: @R.. in fact I need to write machine code.
I tried replacing the asm call by the "(*(void)(*)addr)();", but I also get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @R.. In fact I don't want to do a standard c function call, because I think that requires to push more stuff on the stack (?)

Comment: @univerio I thought adding PROT_EXEC was useless as I already had PROT_WRITE, but when adding PROT_EXEC the segmentation fault does disappear ... Thanks!

Comment: The method call works as well

Comment: @Simon: Not useless; `PROT_EXEC` and `PROT_WRITE` are different, and in fact on most hardened systems they are mutually exclusive (i.e. you can never have a mapping with both). As for a C function call, it does not require pushing anything except possibly the arguments; if there are no arguments there's nothing to push. Doing the call from inline asm would only be necessary if you're using a custom calling convention.

Comment: @univerio Can you post your answer so I can validate it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to execute instructions on a memory page, read and write privileges are not enough; it also needs to be marked executable ([`PROT_EXEC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html)).